# Local sensitivity analysis with exponential and uniform distributions as input

Tags: python, monte-carlo, exponential-distribution, sensitivity-analysis

For my thesis I need to run a sensitivity analysis on the input factors for a supply chain model. I am supposed to change the mean and the standard deviation (sd) of all input factors respectively by 5%.
The input factors are 12 distributions (each within a min/max range) which I use to generate random numbers in order to conduct a Monte Carlo Simulation.
6 of the 12 input factors are normally distributed. In this case I can easily adjust mean and sd.

Now my problem:
4 of the 12 input factors are exponentially distributed. For the "normal" monte carlo simulation I generate the numbers by simply using the lambda value. The mean as well as the sd are then generated automatically. **How can I systematically change the mean and sd by 5%?**

I also have the same problem with 2 of 12 input distributions that have a uniform distribution within the min and the max.

I would highly appreciate any help!

Disclaimer: Since I am neither a student with a quantitative background, nor I speak English as my mother tongue, I apologize for any technical or grammatical mistakes